# flash player loads movie locally, like dead fish on remote

Tags: flash

I am trying to load a flash player onto an html page. The page is housed in my root folder. The flv and swf are both in a folder titled "videos".

The user forum located on the website that created the flash component offered this...make sure the path is pointing to the folder. Right, I get that. But I'm not sure where to find the path. Below is the code for the player in my html page.

Am I not seeing the path here? Should I be looking directly in the fla file? How do I edit the fla. to look in the right folder?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','name','flvPlayer','width','890','height','480','align','top','id','flvPlayer','src','videos/flvPlayer','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','bgcolor','#000000','scale','exactfit','movie','videos/flvPlayer' ); //end AC code
</script><noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" name="flvPlayer" width="890" height="480" align="top" id="flvPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="videos/flvPlayer.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high"><param name="BGCOLOR" value="#000000"><param name="SCALE" value="exactfit">
    <embed src="videos/flvPlayer.swf" width="890" height="480" align="top" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#000000" scale="exactfit" name="flvPlayer"></embed>
  </object></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flash embed code looks fine - you've got the "videos/flvPlayer.swf" in both places that it should be.  I'd expect at this point that your flash host file is loading up properly but the video you're trying to load isn't working.  To fix this you'll need to either edit the .FLA file directly to find the path and filenaname the flash is trying to load or load up a great tool called Fiddler and run the page in IE... you'll be able to see the web requests going back and forth between the browser and the server - you should get a 404 response on the flash movie load which will show you where it is trying to load the video from.

You may wish to have somebody enhance the flvPlayer.swf file to take in the movie path/name as a PARAM so that it can be easily configured in HTML.

[Fiddler Website](http://www.fiddlertool.com)